# PHP laravel error when running any php artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

EDIT: So I am trying to use a Laravel project that I already used before, whenever i use:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I immediately get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class HelloVideo\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/html/orange/php/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:776
```

And afterward, whenever I use any php artisan the same error keeps showing up.

Composer.json:

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
        },
        "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
                "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "database"
                ],
                "psr-4": {
                        "App\\": "app/"
                }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
                "classmap": [
                        "tests/TestCase.php"
                ]
        },
        "scripts": {
                "post-install-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "pre-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled"
                ],
                "post-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
                        "php artisan key:generate"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
        }
}
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` , `composer install`

Comment: whenever I use composer dump-autoload this shows:  [RuntimeException]                                                                                      
  Could not scan for classes inside "tests/TestCase.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

Comment: If not works, can you share your composer.json file?

Comment: I added it in the edit, can you check the errors please?

Comment: remover the `classmap: { "tests/TestCase.php"}`from your composer.

Comment: I did, I edited the question, this is my error i am unable to solve since hours: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class HelloVideo\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/html/orange/php/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:776 
Once I use php artisan migrate this error happens and then any php artisan command i use this shows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your composer.json has the following `psr-4` autoloading configuration:

```json
"psr-4": {
  "App\\": "app/"
}
```

However, it appears the namespace of your app is `HelloVideo`. Change to the following:

```json
"psr-4": {
  "HelloVideo\\": "app/"
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`.